# get_page_by_title() not working as expected

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm looping through an API with jobs and creating new posts from it like this:

```
//fetch jobs and loop through them...
    // check if post title exists, if not add it.
         if ( ! get_page_by_title(html_entity_decode( $post_title ), OBJECT, 'jobs')) :

        // create new post
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        // set post terms
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tags);

        // create tweets through webhook via zapier   
            $tweet = 'webhook content here';
            wp_remote_post( $tweet );

       endif;
```

This works well for the posts, but for some reason if I'm looping through a 100 jobs, each time a 100 tweets are created and I don't understand why because it's not creating a 100 new posts with the same title.

How do I call the webhook if it's a new job that hasn't been added yet?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your method, but I wouldn't verify content this way. This is a fairly intense function for just seeing if something already exists. It might be better to store a unique ID or other attribute in postmeta that you could check if it already exists.

Comment: I'm looping through external data sources for https://workfromhomejobs.me, they don't have identifiers, the title is the only thing I can check against.

Comment: I just don't understand why the wp_remote_post is executed, but not wp_insert_post...

Comment: You're checking your `$post_id`? It could be firing, but throwing an error.

Comment: What does `$my_post` look like? Is `html_entity_decode( $post_title )` the same as the title of the newly created post?

Comment: What do you mean checking $post_id?

$my_post has all the post details above and is working correctly. $post_title is 99% of the time unique, although some jobs titles keep getting added over and over again (which is super annoying).